# throwing an instance of 'HPHP::RescheduleException' - Compile failed on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, hiphop

CentOS 5.8 --- Kenrel 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 x86_64

This is strange error with 64bit CentOS 5, I ran out of luck...

```
[ 89%] Built target ext_hhvm_static
Scanning dependencies of target hphp
[ 89%] Building CXX object src/hphp/CMakeFiles/hphp.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/hiphop/hiphop-php/src/hphp/main.cpp:44:
/opt/hiphop/hiphop-php/src/runtime/base/compiler_id.h:16:1: warning: "COMPILER_ID"   redefined
<command-line>: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

[ 89%] Building CXX object src/hphp/CMakeFiles/hphp.dir/externals.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable hphp
Building hhvm
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'HPHP::RescheduleException'
terminate called recursively
Core dumped: Aborted
hphp failed
make[2]: *** [src/hphp/hphp] Error 255
make[1]: *** [src/hphp/CMakeFiles/hphp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now that HHVM is the default runtime, do a `git pull` and try again.